# Network Library for C

Tags: c, networking, nio

I am looking for a NIO type of library for C. I want to implement a multi threaded UDP network server that will have a lot of clients connecting to it.

Instead of attempting to code my own program to handle packets and 'connections'. I thought I would have a look if there is not already an existing library that has been tested and build for scalability and high performance.

I have found a few for Java but none for C. such as Apache Mina.

I am hoping that some one out there knows of a good one that may assist me. 
Thaks

Comment: Nitpick about "code my own classes": C does not have classes.

Comment: An important detail missing: which operating system? Please [edit] the question to add appropriate tags or explanation. C itself does not have networking stuff, and I think networking libs are often OS specific.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want something to abstract `select()`, `poll()`, or whatever the most efficient mechanism is for your platform.

Have you looked at [libevent](http://libevent.org/) and [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)? There is a nice writeup [here](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/poll-vs-select.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, C has no classes. Secondly, C provides you with everything you need to implement a scalable and high performance solution. It's more low level than java's NIO, but there are good tutorials out there in google.

And if you want a library - try [boosts' asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). It is C++, but perhaps you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux I strongly recommend you to use the POSIX API. It gives you resources for multithreading and networking acrosss any Linux box.

[GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#toc_Sockets)